# How to run Facebook Sample Apps on Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I've been trying to run the Facebook SDK sample apps (Scrumptious, FriendPickerSample, etc.) but to no avail. I had a folder called 'samples' within the Facebook SDK folder that I imported as a project. I then was able to run any of the sample apps within the Android Studio window. However whenever I ran one of the app I would get 100 errors and 12 warnings:

```js
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\Session.java
Error:(24, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(25, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(1065, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session
Error:(1090, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session
Error:(1916, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest
Error:(2129, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest
Error:(2233, 38) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session.NewPermissionsRequest
Error:(2255, 38) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.Session.NewPermissionsRequest
Warning:(28, 22) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Error:(1017, 58) java: reference to OpenRequest is ambiguous, both constructor OpenRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest and constructor OpenRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest match
Error:(1044, 17) java: reference to OpenRequest is ambiguous, both constructor OpenRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest and constructor OpenRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest match
Error:(1570, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class com.facebook.Session
Error:(2121, 13) java: reference to AuthorizationRequest is ambiguous, both constructor AuthorizationRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest and constructor AuthorizationRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest match
Error:(2223, 13) java: reference to AuthorizationRequest is ambiguous, both constructor AuthorizationRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest and constructor AuthorizationRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest match
Error:(2245, 13) java: reference to AuthorizationRequest is ambiguous, both constructor AuthorizationRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest and constructor AuthorizationRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.AuthorizationRequest match
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\AppEventsLogger.java
Error:(24, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(26, 13) java: package bolts does not exist
Error:(809, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class com.facebook.AppEventsLogger
Error:(1000, 30) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable AppLinks
  location: class com.facebook.AppEventsLogger
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\FacebookDialog.java
Error:(27, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(320, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog
Error:(324, 47) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog
Error:(513, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog
Error:(575, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog.Builder<CONCRETE>
Error:(629, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog.Builder<CONCRETE>
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\FacebookFragment.java
Error:(21, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(42, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Fragment
Error:(48, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
Error:(49, 45) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
Error:(46, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(59, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
Error:(60, 58) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method getActivity()
Error:(57, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(65, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
Error:(63, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(266, 55) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.FacebookFragment
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\internal\SessionTracker.java
Error:(23, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(37, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class com.facebook.internal.SessionTracker
Error:(76, 33) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class com.facebook.internal.SessionTracker
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\PickerFragment.java
Error:(24, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(25, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(26, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(55, 69) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Fragment
Error:(120, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(118, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(133, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(131, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(152, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(185, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(187, 45) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(207, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getView()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(183, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(223, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(221, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(234, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(232, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(248, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(243, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(253, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Error:(251, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(568, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getString(int)
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>
Warning:(654, 25) java: setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in android.view.View has been deprecated
Warning:(676, 31) java: setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in android.view.View has been deprecated
Error:(884, 38) java: package LoaderManager does not exist
Error:(883, 51) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getLoaderManager()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>.LoadingStrategy
Error:(941, 24) java: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
  first type:  com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader<T>
  second type: <nulltype>
Error:(947, 24) java: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
  first type:  com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader<T>
  second type: <nulltype>
Error:(958, 51) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment<T>.LoadingStrategy
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\GraphObjectPagingLoader.java
Error:(21, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(27, 62) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Loader
Error:(108, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isStarted()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader<T>
Error:(109, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader<T>
Error:(103, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(119, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader<T>
Error:(117, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\LikeView.java
Error:(27, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\internal\LikeActionController.java
Error:(24, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\internal\Utility.java
Warning:(31, 22) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Warning:(563, 9) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Warning:(563, 41) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Warning:(564, 20) java: sync() in android.webkit.CookieSyncManager has been deprecated
Warning:(581, 22) java: removeExpiredCookie() in android.webkit.CookieManager has been deprecated
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\FacebookAppLinkResolver.java
Error:(21, 13) java: package bolts does not exist
Error:(22, 13) java: package bolts does not exist
Error:(23, 13) java: package bolts does not exist
Error:(24, 13) java: package bolts does not exist
Error:(37, 49) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class AppLinkResolver
Error:(48, 32) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class com.facebook.FacebookAppLinkResolver
Error:(58, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class com.facebook.FacebookAppLinkResolver
Error:(58, 17) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class com.facebook.FacebookAppLinkResolver
Error:(80, 12) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Task
  location: class com.facebook.FacebookAppLinkResolver
Error:(80, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AppLink
  location: class com.facebook.FacebookAppLinkResolver
Error:(182, 27) java: package AppLink does not exist
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\UiLifecycleHelper.java
Error:(25, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
Error:(56, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class LocalBroadcastManager
  location: class com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\BoltsMeasurementEventListener.java
Error:(8, 34) java: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\LoginButton.java
Error:(30, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(91, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
Error:(630, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Fragment
  location: class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\AuthorizationClient.java
Warning:(654, 17) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Warning:(654, 49) java: android.webkit.CookieSyncManager in android.webkit has been deprecated
Warning:(655, 28) java: sync() in android.webkit.CookieSyncManager has been deprecated
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\WebDialog.java
Warning:(391, 30) java: setSavePassword(boolean) in android.webkit.WebSettings has been deprecated
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\android\Facebook.java
Error:(308, 43) java: reference to OpenRequest is ambiguous, both constructor OpenRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest and constructor OpenRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest match
Error:(959, 21) java: reference to OpenRequest is ambiguous, both constructor OpenRequest(android.app.Activity) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest and constructor OpenRequest(Fragment) in com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest match
C:\Users\Randall\Documents\AppDevelopment\SDKs\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\src\com\facebook\widget\PlacePickerFragment.java
Error:(264, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
Error:(280, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method onAttach(android.app.Activity)
Error:(283, 58) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
Error:(278, 5) java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(293, 58) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActivity()
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
Error:(320, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getString(int)
  location: class com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment
Error:(325, 64) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method getActivity()
```

This seems odd to me because all these errors are coming from the facebook sdk such as Session.java. Here's a screenshot of my project view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxlN4.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any luck on this error @realnessray ??

Answer (score 1):

Okay,I am quiet new at this
but I think your Project doesn't have the support-v4 library.
Its the library that is being used by facebook for fragments and Broadcast Managers in your Project.
You can use the facebook Login button without a Fragment but its advised to use it with fragments

> just add the following line in your Gradle build dependencies
>
> > compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'

i think it should work